# How to use Windows Search Service instead of the old indexing service to index files?

Tags: vb.net, search, indexing, windows-server-2008, oledb

In the past I had the indexing service installed on a Windows Server 2003 and used it to index files for my website. I did this by executing an OleDbCommand with a query and a connection string.

How do I accomplish the same thing with the new "Windows Search Service" (Windows Server 2008) by using VB.NET? Does this work the same way so that I only need to change the Provider name which has been "MSIDXS.1" up to now? Case true, what is the new Provider name?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found some decent (thought typically fun to read */sarcasm*) MSDN information here:  [MSDN Windows Search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266516(VS.85).aspx).  You also may try the SDK out, it seems to have some samples and whatnot included on how to code for WinSearch 3 [Windows Search SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=645300AE-5E7A-4CE7-95F0-49793F8F76E8&displaylang=en)